# nginx container is running php from host

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, containers

I have two containers PHP and nginx linked between them and i want that nginx container run PHP from php container. Now it's running PHP from my host machine. How can i fix that. Bellow is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

> ```
> > version: '3' 
> > services:   
> >   nginx:
> >     image: nginx:alpine
> >     volumes:
> >       - ./app:/app
> >       - ./nginx-config/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
> >     ports:
> >       - 80:80
> >     depends_on:
> >       - php   
> >   php:
> >     image: php:7.3-fpm-alpine
> >     volumes:
> >      - ./app:/app
> ```

Comment: When you say "running", how does that happen?  How can you tell it's not using the container version?  Can you include enough of your nginx configuration to be a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into [dockerize-nginx-php](https://github.com/Adiii717/dockerize-nginx-php/blob/master/README.md#to-run-container-with-build-time-code) docker-compose file, it supports both build time code for `php` and `nginx` and also support run code from mounting host volumes.

```
git clone https://github.com/Adiii717/dockerize-nginx-php.git
cd dockerize-nginx-php;
docker-compose -f docker-compose-buildtime.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose-buildtime.yml up
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    image: nginxbuild_time
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.php
    image: php
```

dockerfile.php

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app
```

Dockerfile.nginx

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx-config /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY app /app
```

So @Ahmed resolves the issue by installing composer within container.

> The problem is to install composer under php container. So i added a command to install composer in the DockerFile of PHP. Thanks for your support!

Comment: it's usually the same thing. It is detecting php on the host machine wich is in the version 7.0.3. https://i.ibb.co/wBrbzYk/Capture-du-2020-07-13-12-02-04.png

Comment: You can change your version of PHP temporarely. And run docker-compose. You will find the same thing ! It detect the php version of the host

Comment: I do not think, docker container has running on process space.

Comment: If i'm running on the host php 7.0.33 and in the container running PHP 7.2.33. Logically, the problem should not appear.

Comment: Fixed. The problem is to install composer under php container. So i added a command to install composer  in the DockerFile of PHP. Thanks for your support !

Comment: awsome, let me add in the answer so will help in future someone lese.